# Using New-Item cmdlet with Literalpath in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-v5.1

I'm using `New-Item` cmdlet to create a new folder and surprisingly find that it has no `-Literalpath` parameter available. My path contains square brackets in it. What can I do to address this problem?

Comment: `> New-Item "this is [some] path" -ItemType "directory"` this seems to be working for me. It works as well with full path. Could it be you are trying this without brackets ? Brackets are not in the [Forbidden characters and names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file)

Comment: You can have square brackets in the item name....: `New-Item -Path "/the/path/to/your[file]here.txt"  -ItemType Directory`

Comment: @Bakudan @Stuart Yes, I can use brackets in the name of a newly created file/directory but not `-Path`. Say this code `New-Item -Path "G:\1\jj[jj]j" -Name "121" -ItemType Directory`

Comment: @preachers `New-Item -Path "G:\1\jj[jj]j\jj[dqiw]j" -Type Directory`. Problem solved.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Thank you. I should have thought of that! It's so easy.

Answer (score 1):

So, it was a little bit confusing what was the actual problem. So, you need to escape the brackets, the same way you would [escape "\n" in strings](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/07/powertip-new-lines-with-powershell/) - with " ` ".  This will create the folder:

```
> New-Item -Path 'C:\stuff\powershell\`[test`]' -Name "221" -ItemType "directory"
```

But this will "silently fail":

```
> New-Item -Path 'C:\stuff\powershell\[test]' -Name "221" -ItemType "directory"
```

Comment: It's not a problem if it's a single instance. In my case, however, the `New-Item` cmdlet is in a script with random paths feeding to it. So the escape way won't work.

Comment: @preachers then you should be able to do `>cd [test]` or `>cd '[test]'` ?

Comment: this helped me deal with an asterisk in a similar use case, thanks!

Comment: That is an effective workaround, but note that (a) it is only needed if `-Name` is _also_ specified  (specifying the whole path in `-Path` alone works as-is) and (b) it should _never_ be necessary, because the behavior should be considered a _bug_ - see [GitHub issue #17106](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17106)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is surprising that [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) has no `-LiteralPath` parameter, especially given that:

- its **`-Path` parameter *behaves like* a `-LiteralPath` parameter**, i.e. it treats the path as a *literal* (verbatim) one.

  - As for a potential future enhancement: While *renaming* the parameter isn't an option so as not to break backward compatibility, conceivably `-LiteralPath` could be introduced as an *alias* of `-Path`.
- ***except* if a `-Name` argument is also supplied**, in which case the `-Path` argument is unexpectedly treated as a [*wildcard expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), which notably causes problems with file paths that contain `[`

  - This behavior **should be considered a *bug*** - see [GitHub issue #17106](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17106)

    - A related bug is that the path passed to the `-Target` (aka `-Value`) parameter too is interpreted as a wildcard expression - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65551184/45375) and [GitHub issue #14534](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14534).
  - The workaround is to not use `-Name` and instead join the name component to the `-Path` argument, such as with [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path)

```bash
# OK - with only a -Path argument, the path is taken *literally*
# Creates a subdir. literally named '[test]' with a file 'test.txt' in it.
New-Item -Force -Path '[test]\test.txt'

# !! BROKEN - with -Name also present, the -Path argument is
# !! interpreted as a *wildcard expression*
New-Item -Force -Path '[test]' -Name 'test.txt'

# WORKAROUND - use -Path only.
New-Item -Force -Path (Join-Path '[test]' 'test.txt')
```

Comment: The workaround doesn't work if the `name` is unrelated to the `value` eg. `New-Item -Type SymbolicLink -Name 'myShortcut' -Value '../to[another].file'` (as mentioned in your #17106)

Comment: @Hashbrown, in case you're referring to the conceptually related, but separate issue of the `-Value` parameter inappropriately being interpreted as a wildcard expression as well, that is the subject of [GitHub issue #13136](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13136). Fixing that has actually been green-lit, but no one has stepped up to implement it.

Comment: To add insult to injury, the current workaround for treating `-Value` literally is to escape the wildcard metacharacters twice(!): `New-Item -Type SymbolicLink -Name 'myShortcut' -Value '../to\`\`[another\`\`].file' `- see [GitHub issue #14534](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14534)