# Cannot find path _ because it does not exist

Tags: powershell, hardlink, new-item

I'm trying to create small script in powershell that would move files and directories to correct localizations. I made the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\list\' | ForEach-Object { if ($($_.Name) -like '*[1]*') {
$file = $($_.Name)
$path = $($_.FullName)
echo "$file  ==>  $path"
Move-Item -Path $path -Destination .\[1]\}}
```

and it detects correct files and directories, but doesn't move them.
Then I decided to modify command a bit and create hardlinks instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\list\' | ForEach-Object { if ($($_.Name) -like '*[1]*') {
$file = $($_.Name)
$path = $($_.FullName)
echo "$file  ==>  $path"
New-Item -Path ".\``[1``]\" -Name $file -Type HardLink -Target "$path"}}
```

and I received the following response (cut to only 1 loop):

```
[1] dir1  ==>  D:\test_move\list\[1] dir1
New-Item:
Line |
   5 |  New-Item -Path ".\``[1``]\" -Name $file -Type HardLink -Target "$path …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find path 'D:\test_move\list\[1] dir1' because it does not exist.
```

The same error appears both with and without administrative privileges.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: If the path does not contain wildcards, then `-LiteralPath` may be a better choice since `[]` is syntax for a wildcard character range

Comment: I forgot about -LiteralPath parameter and it works with Move-Object part. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath .\list -File -Filter '*[1]*' | ForEach-Object { 
  $file = $_.Name
  $path = $_.FullName
  "$file  ==>  $path" # implicit `echo` aka `Write-Output`
  New-Item -Force -Type HardLink `
           -Path (Join-Path .\[1] $file) `
           -Target ([WildcardPattern]::Escape($path)) ` # !! see PowerShell Core comments below
           -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- `-Filter '*[1]*'` prefilters the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) output to only include files whose name contains substring `[1]` *verbatim*, because the `-Filter` parameter uses a *filesystem-native* wildcard language that does *not* treat `[` and `]` as metacharacters.

  - By contrast, with PowerShell's more powerful [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), `'*[1]*'` would match any name that contains just `1`, because the `[...]` is interpreted as a character set or range. With the `-like`, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) operator, you'd have to use `` '*`[1`]*' `` (escaping of the metacharacters to be interpreted verbatim with `` ` ``) to find verbatim `[1]` substrings.
- `-File` limits matching items to *files*, because *hardlinks* are only supported for files, not also directories.
- `-Path (Join-Path .\[1] $file)` use *only* a `-Path` argument - rather than a directory-path-only `-Path` argument combined with a filename-only `-Name` argument - which ensures that the argument is treated as a *literal* (verbatim) path, without interpretation of wildcard metacharacters such as `[` and `]`.

  - Regrettably, combining `-Path` with `-Name` causes the `-Path` argument to be interpreted as a *wildcard pattern*.
- `-Force` creates the target *directory* on demand, if needed, but note that it would also replace any *preexisting* target file.
- ***Windows PowerShell***: `([WildcardPattern]::Escape($path))` **escapes the 
  `-Target` (aka `-Value`) argument (target path) in order to treat it *verbatim*, because it is - unfortunately - interpreted *as a wildcard pattern***. Not performing this escaping prompted the error you saw.

  - **Caveat**:

    - **In *PowerShell [Core] 7+*, a breaking change was approved** in [GitHub proposal #13136](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13136) to - more sensibly - **treat the `-Target` argument as a *literal* (verbatim) path**, in which case you would **simply use `-Target $path`**.
    - However, **as of PowerShell 7.3.8 this change isn't implemented yet, and, unfortunately, targeting a path that contains `[` and `]` is currently *broken altogether*** - see [GitHub issue #14534](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14534).

      - **As of PowerShell 7.3.8 you must escape *twice*(!)** to make it work: `([WildcardPattern]::Escape([WildcardPattern]::Escape($path)))`

Note that many, but not all, file-processing cmdlets offer a `-LiteralPath` parameter to explicitly pass paths to be taken *literally* (verbatim), whereas the  `-Path` parameter - usually the *implied* parameter for the first *positional* argument - is designed to accept wildcard patterns.

Therefore, your could have made your original approach with [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) work as follows:

```
# Ensure that the target dir. exists.
# No escaping needed for -Path when not combined with -Name.
$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Path .\[1] -Force 

# Move the file, targeted with -LiteralPath, there.
# No escaping needed for -Destination.
Move-Item -LiteralPath $path -Destination .\[1]\
```

Note: Unlike with `New-Item`, `Move-Item`'s `-Force` does *not* create the target directory on demand. On the flip side, `Move-Item`'s `-Destination` more sensibly interprets its argument *literally* (verbatim), unlike `New-Item`'s `-Target` parameter.

Comment: sadly the hardlink part is not working as it returns pretty much similar error: Could not find item D:\test_move\list\`[1`] file.txt.

Comment: OK, so I tried something - i moved `([WildcardPattern]::Escape($path))` to the `$path` initialization - and it worked. Powershell never stops to amaze me. Marking this answer as accepted. (also I just remembered that we can't create hardlinks of directories... gonna try something else)

Comment: @plW0lf, I'm glad to hear it, but I wouldn't expect that to make a difference. When I try the code as shown (first snippet), it works for me in _Windows PowerShell v5.1_. By contrast, in _PowerShell [Core] 7+_ using escaped paths appears to be broken altogether.

Comment: @plW0lf: Yes, hardlinks can only point to _files_, which is why I used the `-File` switch in the answer.

Comment: @plW0lf: By contrast, `-Type SymbolicLink` supports directories too, but by default you must run _elevated_ (as admin) to create them.

Comment: @plW0lf: Finally, you can go back to your original plan and _move_ the items of interest, as shown in the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: Well, I'm using Powershell 7, so that explains everything

Comment: @plW0lf: I see. While the `powershell` tag will presumably increasingly be used for PowerShell [Core] 7+, it doesn't hurt to use the `powershell-core` tag as well, or to at least mention the use of 7+ in the question body. Please also see my update re planned changes in behavior ("Caveat")